# Probability distribution of the middle element for sorted three random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $x_a$, $x_b$, and $x_c$ be three random samples from a PDF $f(x)$. The samples are then sorted into $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ in ascending order. How do I get the distribution of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$? Is there a generalization for this for more samples?

I have solved the case for $x_1$ and $x_3$ (or $x_n$ in the general case) with min and max convolutions, but I can't make it work with the intermediate cases. My attempt was $P(x_2)\ \alpha \ P(x_b|x_a<x_b)P(x_b|x_b<x_c)$ then normalizing it, but it doesn't seem to hold up when I manually solved it on the case of a fair dice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: Woah, thanks. I used lots of keywords when trying to look for resources online, but I didn't think of the word "order".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, these are [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). If the cumulative distribution function corresponding to $f$ is $F$, the cumulative distribution functions for the $x_i$ are

$$
F_i(x)=\sum_{j=i}^3\binom3jF(x)^j(1-F(x))^{3-j}\;,
$$

so

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_1(x)
&=&
1-(1-F(x))^3\;,
\\
F_2(x)
&=&
(3-2F(x))F(x)^2\;,
\\
F_3(x)
&=&
F(x)^3\;.
\end{eqnarray*}